# How do I get Mario's hat back after pressing the Yellow Switch?

Tags: b3313

In the ["abandoned" version 0.9](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Versions) of B3313 (a ROM hack of Super Mario 64), I activated the [Yellow Switch](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_Yellow_Switch_Palace) which caused Mario to lose his hat. Just like the original version of Super Mario 64, Mario's hat stays missing even after restarting the game. The B3313 wiki says you can get Mario's hat back in the [Desert Maze](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Desert_Maze), but I can't find the stage due to the game's confusing castle layout.

How do I get Mario's hat back after pressing the Yellow Switch?

[image: Mario without his hat]

Comment: The [warps section](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Desert_Maze#Warps) mentions something, does that tell you what you need to know? `Plexal Basement: In the main section's front side, go through the door with the number 2 on it, up against the Lethal Lava Land painting, and then through the hole.`

Comment: @JeffMercado I saw the warp but initially couldn't find a path to Plexal Basement. After looking again, I think I can travel from Castle Grounds > Beta Lobby A > Beta Lobby B > Beta Lobby C > Beta Lobby D > Plexal Basement > Desert Maze.

Comment: @Stevoisiak, the wiki says you can get it if you lost it in the metal cap, but you lost it in the yellow switch

Comment: While it is better to *avoid* the switch in the first place, the fact that you can technically press it again AND the "hat removal" not being 100% made me wonder... Can you actually press the switch multiple times until you are lucky and none of the  "Hat stolen" flags get activated? Probably not worth testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hat was lost from pressing the Yellow Switch, you cannot get it back at the Desert Maze. Klepto will not have your cap. As far as I can tell, there is no way to get your cap back after pressing the Yellow Switch outside of switching to a different save file.

[image: Capless mario looking at Klepto not carrying hat]

If you still want to reach the Desert Maze, I found the following route which requires at least 1 red star.

- Pause the game and hit A to fast travel. If you have at least 1 red star, each time you fast travel you will be taken to a different but near-identical looking castle lobby.
- Fast travel until you reach [Beta Lobby C](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Lobby_C). It will have numbered doors labeled 3, 3, 1, and 3.
- Enter the left-most door labeled 3 to enter [Beta Lobby D](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Lobby_D).
- Enter one of the two unlabeled "basement" doors in the middle then enter the key door at the end of the hall to reach [Plexal Basement](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Plexal_Basement)
- Walk through the key door and immediately take two sharp lefts to enter the door labeled 2.
- Jump in the hole to enter [Desert Maze](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Desert_Maze).
- Head down the left path until you see Klepto.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get your hat back, but there was a 6.25% chance that you did not lose your hat, but you lost your hat.